# Unable to implement Event Listener in latest Java Cucumber Maven project with JUnit5

Tags: addeventlistener, junit5, event-listener, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Created a new Java Cucumber project with the command -

mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=io.cucumber" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=cucumber-archetype"  "-DarchetypeVersion=7.14.0" "-DgroupId=hellocucumber"  "-DartifactId=hellocucumber"  "-Dpackage=hellocucumber" "-Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" "-DinteractiveMode=false"

Created a Custom Listener class with
public class MyListener implements EventListener { . . . }

Since @CucumberOptions is not available in the latest version, can you please suggest how to register this MyListener class as a listener for execution ?
This is to listen to events for - Before beginning the execution, After end of all scenarios etc.

Searched many blogs. But could not find relevant answers. Almost all blogs are referring to earlier versions of Cucumber where @CucumberOptions is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ConfigurationParameter` annotation from JUnit 5 to set the `cucumber.plugin` property. For example:

```java
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("io/cucumber/skeleton")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "io.cucumber.skeleton")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

To target your plugin you would use the value `your.package.MyListener`, for multiple plugins you'd use a comma separated list.

You can also set the `cucumber.plugin` property in the `junit-platform.propeties` file.

It's worth reading the documentation from the JUnit Platform and Cucumbers JUnit Platform Engine:

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Appreciate it.